# How to name only particular rows in a df in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I recently tried to name only part of rows in my dataframe, but don't know how to do this. I thought that maybe 'row.names' for df could help, but it looks like I can't name some rows, I must name all rows to make it work. 
At least this code didn't change any row names:

```
example_df <- data.frame(rnorm(5), rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
row.names(example_df[c(1,2),]) <- c('11', '12')
row.names(example_df[3,]) <- 'a'
```

So how can I change only part of row names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work -

```
example_df <- data.frame(rnorm(5), rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
row.names(example_df)[1:2] <- c('11', '12')
row.names(example_df)[3] <- 'a'

#    rnorm.5. rnorm.5..1  rnorm.5..2
# 11 -0.5374545 -1.0895643 -0.09938087
# 12 -0.6822140 -0.2806339  1.38078815
# a  -0.8664183 -0.5729183 -0.84851810
# 4  -0.9269735  0.4403557 -0.05622809
# 5   2.1156331 -1.1441339 -1.04363951
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Do you know why this code works and the other one doesn't? It seems to me like `row.names(example_df[3,]` and `row.names(example_df)[3]` is the same thing, but apparently isn't.

Comment: I am just wild guessing here - maybe using `example_df[3, ]` argument for `row.names` does not actually point it to `example_df` object in global envir. You should ask this as separate question so that more experienced programmers can provide you with a correct answer.